# Generating a C++ Code Coverage Report with Colcon

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just trying to create something similar to the ROS 2 CI for code coverage (example [here](https://ci.ros2.org/job/ci_linux_coverage/lastBuild/cobertura/)).

With colcon mixins, I've seen `coverage-gcc` under `build` mixins, but I'm not sure how to use it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355388/generating-a-c++-code-coverage-report-with-colcon/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2020-06-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those curious, I was able to do it by invoking `colcon` as follows.

```
colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="--coverage" -DCMAKE_CXX_OUTPUT_EXTENSION_REPLACE=ON
```

Then I ran the tests.

```
colcon test
```

Finally, I ran `lcov`.

```
lcov --capture --directory build/ --output-file my_fantastic_coverage_report.info
```

And generated fancy HTML with this.

```
genhtml my_fantastic_coverage_report.info --output-directory fancy_html_coverage_report
```

Then just `sensible-browser fancy_html_coverage_report/index.html`.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2020-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-05**:
For CI purposes, the following PR may be interesting: [ros-industrial/industrial_ci/pull/504](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_ci/pull/504).

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-07-06**:
The colcon mixin repository provides a `mixin` to generate C++ coverage (https://github.com/colcon/colcon-mixin-repository/blob/1ddb69bedfd1f04c2f000e95452f7c24a4d6176b/coverage.mixin#L3-L8) which contains all the CMake arguments you need.

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2021-11-05**:
That's nice to get back the details of the commands but can you get back the CmakeModule to directly generate report as new target ?